# Azure App Services app uses wrong PHP version

Tags: php, azure, azure-web-app-service

I've installed/deployed a WordPress instance to Azure App Services (using https://github.com/azureappserviceoss/wordpress-azure).

The Azure interface (under Application Settings) reports PHP v7 as being used, Azure Console confirms this.
But when I print a `phpinfo()` statement (in a `test.php` file in the WordPress' `wwwroot`), it displays `PHP Version 5.4.45`.

Anyone got any idea what might be wrong, or at least how to further troubleshoot this?

I've already tried quite a lot of things: changing PHP version in the interface, adding a custom PHP binary, restarting the App Service, ...

Comment: To isolate, do you see the same if you create an empty app and just add that single test.php file?

Comment: Same issue here, did you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have installed a custom `PHP 5.4.45` runtime on Azure Web App.

[image]

As you can see, there is no PHP 5.4.x we can use on Azure App Service. So, please scroll to the **Handler mappings** section in **Application Settings** to double check whether you have configured any `php-cgi.exe` on it. If yes, you'll need to delete it then click **Save** button.

[image]